# Android Architecture Components Lifecycle state

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html

> STARTED 
>   Lifecycle.State STARTED
>   For an Activity, this state is reached in two cases: after onStart
>   call; right before onPause call.

As the above documentation says, I couldn't understand the rationale behind the STARTED state right before onPause call. Can someone please explain that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Notice that the values in the [`Lifecycle.State` `enum`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html) do not include a `PAUSED` state. There are only five states: `CREATED, DESTROYED, INITIALIZED, RESUMED, STARTED`. These do not exactly correspond with the normal Activity lifecycle that we all know and love:

[image: Lifecycle states]

Also note the following from the [Lifecycle class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html):

> ON_CREATE, ON_START, ON_RESUME events in this class are dispatched after the LifecycleOwner's related method returns.
>    ON_PAUSE, ON_STOP, ON_DESTROY events in this class are dispatched **before** the LifecycleOwner's related method is called

The execution of the `onPause()` is the closing boundary for the `RESUMED` state.  At this point, the Activity is no longer considered `RESUMED` and it is certainly not `DESTROYED`. Since we don't have a `PAUSED` state it follows it must now be in the `STARTED` state. This is technically true, the Activity hasn't yet stopped but it is no longer resumed.

Comment: Thanks David for the helpful reply.

As per the [Lifecycle diagram](https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle-states.png)
 does this mean the activity will remain in a STARTED state while it is paused and in CREATED state while it is stopped?

Comment: @AsheshBharadwaj thanks, that picture makes it even clearer

Comment: Thanks for putting up the image. By mistake I hit enter while typing my comment.  Can you please look at my previous comment?

Comment: @Ashesh The answer to your question is a qualified "yes". The technical way of saying it is as per the documentation

Comment: any thoughts about this rationale? Why not use PAUSED and STOPPED state?

Comment: @Ashesh perhaps because it is easier to compare states like that

Comment: Wait I don't understand. How can I check if the current state is paused/stopped ? Or to register to it?